# How to remove old indices of Jaeger in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, jaeger

I use Jaeger with Elasticsearch and I want to remove old indices. I tried `jaeger-es-index-cleaner`, see [Remove old data](https://www.jaegertracing.io/docs/1.22/deployment/#remove-old-data):

> **Remove old data**
>
> The historical data can be removed with the `jaeger-es-index-cleaner` that is also used for daily indices.
>
> ```
> docker run -it --rm --net=host -e ROLLOVER=true jaegertracing/jaeger-es-index-cleaner:latest 14 http://localhost:9200 # <1>
> ```
>
> <1> Remove indices older than 14 days.

**Log**

I tried to delete all indices older than 2 days, but no indice was deleted:

```
$ docker run -it --rm --net=host -e ROLLOVER=true jaegertracing/jaeger-es-index-cleaner:latest 2 http://localhost:9200
No indices to delete
```

**Indices**

If I list all indices with `http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices`, I still see old indices:

```
yellow open jaeger-service-2021-04-09      vhdjlv5BR9yHhFgqmemiPA 5 1      70  1  38.6kb  38.6kb
yellow open jaeger-span-2021-04-09         Z-o78_oiStuiEdDJO79_6Q 5 1   49091  0     2mb     2mb
yellow open jaeger-dependencies-2021-04-13 tgCw5vK1SeG5oa6m-4osBQ 1 1       1  0     9kb     9kb
yellow open jaeger-service-2021-04-12      zi2ifth0RVKxyYNlfqe4kA 5 1      87  1  66.4kb  66.4kb
yellow open jaeger-span-2021-04-12         DeDPz2kNQKWiTI5v5rgKTg 5 1 5780283  0 188.5mb 188.5mb
yellow open jaeger-service-2021-04-13      vztAwPDPS2-okqywSGOIxw 5 1      81 22  70.7kb  70.7kb
yellow open jaeger-span-2021-04-13         SMJA7pJrQ6qZYsTXnwQVsw 5 1 4102841  0   141mb   141mb
```

**Question**

How to delete old indices of Jaeger from Elasticsearch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing `-e ROLLOVER=true` did it:

```
$ docker run -it --rm --net=host jaegertracing/jaeger-es-index-cleaner:latest 2 http://localhost:9200
```

Comment: ,I had rollover enabled already. For me It was some issues with Jaeger operator, which I deleted and spun again, which resolved the issue. Glad that your issue got resolved and thanks for letting me know.